Can't get Cognito logout functionality to work with ALB
I am able to log in fine using Cognito, but I can't get the logout functionality working following the standard steps:

Sign the user out of the idp with cognito_idp.admin_user_global_sign_out()
Set new, expired ALB cookies to delete the existing ones
Redirecting to the Cognito logout url

There are no errors and the redirect works, but I am then able to go to website without having to login again.
The backend (FastAPI) route looks like:
@app.get("/sign_out")
async def sign_out(request: Request, response: Response):
    
    cognito = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name=<region_name>)

    headers = request.headers
    identity = headers['x-amzn-oidc-identity']
    cognito.admin_user_global_sign_out(
        UserPoolId=<user pool ID>,
        Username=identity
    )

    response.set_cookie(
        key="AWSALB",
        value="-",
        httponly=False,
        max_age=0
    )

    response.set_cookie(
        key="AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0",
        value="-",
        httponly=False,
        max_age=0
    )

    response.set_cookie(
        key="AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-1",
        value="-",
        httponly=False,
        max_age=0
    )

    response.set_cookie(
        key="AWSALBCORS",
        value="-",
        httponly=False,
        max_age=0
    )

    response.set_cookie(
        key="AWSALBAuthNonce",
        value="-",
        httponly=False,
        max_age=0
    )

    return RedirectResponse(url="https://<domain>.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=<client ID>&logout_uri=https://example.com/")

Extra info:

The app client has https://example.com/ set as an Allowed Sign Out URL
The app client has aws.cognito.signin.user.admin, email, openid, and phone scopes
I have given the EC2 full admin permissions to ensure that this wasn't a problem
Using the default ELB setup

UPDATE
Having agonised over this for hours, I have seen some progress by going to the ALB listener that routes to the application, and configuring Edit listener -> Advanced authentication settings -> Session timeout to 1 second (the default was 7 days).
This then means that you can log in as before, but now the logout functionality also works.
However, this is unfortunately causing the app to not work as it should when logged in.  E.g. when you try to make a POST request to the backend via fetch I get the following error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://<domain>.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?etc.etc. {Reason CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I can't see how this is related to the ALB session timeout, especially as this doesn't seem to cause problems to GET requests!
So, at this point, I'm not sure if there is an easy fix to the new CORS issue, or if the session timeout is a bad fix to the original problem and that there is a better solution that I'm unaware of.
